# How to split a sequential integer array, if any sequence is missing

Tags: arrays, swift

Supposre I have an input array of integers. I want to split this array in multiple array based on the missing integer and append it in a new Array. I think `split` can be used here but not sure how to do it. I want `arrayFinal` only.

```
myArray = [0,1,2,4,7,8]
```

**Desired Output**

```
arrayOne = [0,1,2]
arrayTwo = [4]
arrayThree = [7,8]
arrayFinal = [[0,1,2], [4], [7,8]]
```

Comment: Your code indicates you need dedicated variables for reach array slice, this cannot be achieved in Swift since the input array can vary in contents

Comment: Yes content of input array can varry, but I can sort the array and want to split if the next sequence is missing. I don't think its undoable in swift.

Comment: There's no way to do this using split.  There's no separator to speak of. A for loop comparing the value at each index with the value of the previous is probably the best way.

Comment: With a for loop it's quite easy so it's probably not worth doing anything fancier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just sort your array and iterate them in order. Check if the element minus one is equal to the last element of your 2D array, if true append otherwise append a new array with the element and increase the index of the subarrays:

```
extension Collection where Element == Int {
    func grouped() -> [[Element]] {
        let elements = Set(self).sorted()
        guard let first = elements.first else { return [] }
        var result = [[first]]
        var i = 0
        for element in elements.dropFirst() {
            if element-1 == result[i].last! {
                result[i].append(element)
            } else {
                result.append([element])
                i += 1
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

---

```
let myArray =  [0,1,2,4,7,8]
let grouped = myArray.grouped()    // [[0, 1, 2], [4], [7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an algorithm you're asking for so there are a dozen different ways to do it. Since you are going to have to walk through the array's contents to find the missing integers, I would just create an array and append the numbers to it as you go, then create a new array whenever you hit a gap.

You'll probably have to adjust this for any special cases you might have. "Will this always start at 0 and move in a positive direction?" etc.

Try this out:

```
func splitByMissingInteger(array: [Int]) -> [[Int]]? {
    var arrayFinal :[[Int]] = [ [Int]() ]
    var i = 0
    for num in array{
        if arrayFinal[i].isEmpty || (arrayFinal[i].last == nil){
            arrayFinal[i].append(num)
        } else if num == (arrayFinal[i].last! + 1){
            arrayFinal[i].append(num)
        } else {
            i += 1
            arrayFinal.append([Int]())
            arrayFinal[i].append(num)
        }
    }
    return arrayFinal
}
```